# How to use calculate geometry on non versioned data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-pro, versioning, calculate-geometry

Every time I attempt to use calculate the geometry of some shapefiles I receive this message: ERROR 130051: Input feature class is not registered as versioned.

I did not understand why a mathematical calculation needed versioning.

Key facts

1. The data is all stored locally.
2. The layer that I want measured was created through multiple selections and merges.

The layer started out as two different layers. The first was a map of property parcels in my county. The second was a geological survey for the soil in the county. A selection of large plots was made, then merged with the soil layer so that the individual soil types were divided within each large property.

The goal is to calculate a theoretical crop yield based on soil quality, but there is no way to measure the amount of soil in each parcel because ArcGIS Pro will not make the measurement because the data is not versioned. I cannot publish it as a web layer since selections are forbidden to export. I am not interesting in publishing my unfinished work either. If there is a way to go into the back door to have ArcGIS Pro do this or if I have to use Python please let me know. I do not think this should have such a complex solution but I am all ears.

Comment: Are you using "shapefile" to refer to a non-versioned enterprise geodatabase table?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any joins try to remove them and check if the issue is observed.

And, for your kind info, the issue is a known limitation and it is resolved in the upcoming Pro update, ArcGIS Pro 2.7

Comment: Thank you! It does seem like it works now. I intersected the layers to break up the plots by soil type. It has worked very well.